# Ansible CallbackBase result object content

Tags: callback, ansible

Our dev team provides us an Ansible package to work with. I noticed thy develop a custom stdout_callback and I'm trying to understand it.

I'm looking at the code of the class CallbackBase available [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/8d0c193b251051e459513614e6f7212ecf9f0922/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/__init__.py) and I noticed the result variable but I can't find a description of it's content.

Is there a place I can find such information?

Next question, how does Ansible call such callback? CallbackBase contains several methods but I'd like to know where those methods are called.

Thanks for your feedbacks

Comment: You might find reading [developing plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#callback-plugins) helpful even if it probably does not answer fully your question.

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator, it helped me indeed but I'm still "hungry" if I may say

Comment: I never dug into that so the following is my tldr;-2-minutes-analyze-understanding... callbacks respond to ansible fired events. They are enabled in ansible.cfg so I guess they listen to the relevant events once configured there. These are the methods you see int the base class: `<source>_on_<event>` like `playbook_on_start` that will be called whenever a playbook fires the start event if you implement it in your derived callback class. If you really want to know where this happens in the code, you'll have to dig in there (or be lucky if a better ansible geek than me passes by ;))